# html5 canvas write mutiple font in same line

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I can be able to fill in canvas this:

This is an  **example** of what I want to do

**This is an** example of what **I want to do**

So i received my string in html code, but i parse all the string, and i replace de `<strong>` for #b# and all `</br>` for \n in my servidor.

so i have in my javascript this:

```
c.font = font_size + ' ' + font_family;
          c.fillStyle = color;
          c.textAlign = 'start';
          c.textBaseline = 'top';
          if (this.text_width == 0){  
                  this.text_width = 1024;
          }else{
            this.text_width = this.text_width;
          }
          var DEBUG = true;

          var draw = x !== null && y !== null;

          if (font_size =="8pt" || font_size =="10pt"){
            var lineHeight = 15;
          }

          if (font_size =="11pt" || font_size =="12pt"){
            var lineHeight = 17;
          }
          if (font_size =="14pt" || font_size =="16pt"){
            var lineHeight = 19;
          }
          if (font_size =="18pt" || font_size =="20pt"){
            var lineHeight = 23;
          }
          if (font_size =="22pt" || font_size =="24pt"){
            var lineHeight = 29;
          }
          if (font_size =="26pt" || font_size =="28pt"){
            var lineHeight = 34;
          }
          if (font_size =="30pt" || font_size =="32pt"){
            var lineHeight = 38;
          }
          if (font_size =="34pt"|| font_size =="36pt"){
            var lineHeight = 41;
          }
          if (font_size =="38pt" || font_size =="40pt"){
            var lineHeight = 45;
          }
          if (font_size =="42pt" || font_size =="44pt"){
            var lineHeight = 50;
          }

          fitWidth = this.text_width;
          text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, "\n");
          sections = text.split("\n");

          var i, str, wordWidth, words, currentLine = 0,
              maxHeight = 0,
              maxWidth = 0;

          var printNextLine = function (str) {
            if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
              // see below for better implementation!
              String.prototype.startsWith = function (str){
                return this.indexOf(str) == 0;
              };
            }
                  if (draw) {
                  comp=0;
                  comp2=0;
                  if (str.startsWith("#b#")){
                  bold=str.split("#b#");

                  //alert(bold);
                  //alert(bold);
                  for(i=0;i<bold.length;i++){
                  if(i%2!=0){
                  c.font = "Bold "+font_size + ' ' + font_family;
                  if(i==0){
                  c.fillText(bold[i], x, y + (lineHeight * currentLine));
                  }else{
                  for(var a=0;a<i;a++){
                  comp+=c.measureText(bold[a]).width
                  }

                  c.fillText(bold[i], x+comp, y + (lineHeight * currentLine));
                  }


                  }else{
                  c.font = font_size + ' ' + font_family;
                  for(var b=0;b<i;b++){
                  comp2+=c.measureText(bold[b]).width
                  }
                  c.fillText(" "+bold[i], x+comp2, y + (lineHeight * currentLine));
                  }
                  }
                  }else{
                  if (str.indexOf("#b#") != -1){
                  bold=str.split("#b#");
                  for(i=0;i<bold.length;i++){
                  if(i%2==0){

                  if(i==0){
                  c.font = font_size + ' ' + font_family;
                  c.fillText(bold[i], x, y + (lineHeight * currentLine));
                  }else{
                  for(var a=0;a<i;a++){
                  comp+=c.measureText(bold[a]).width
                  }
                  c.font = font_size + ' ' + font_family;
                  c.fillText(bold[i], x+comp, y + (lineHeight * currentLine));
                  }


                  }else{
                  c.font = "Bold "+font_size + ' ' + font_family;
                  for(var b=0;b<i;b++){
                  comp2+=c.measureText(bold[b]).width
                  }
                  c.fillText(" "+bold[i], x+comp2, y + (lineHeight * currentLine));
                  }
                  }



                  }else{
                  c.font = font_size + ' ' + font_family;
                  c.fillText(str, x, y + (lineHeight * currentLine));
                  }

                  }
                  }

                  currentLine++;
                  wordWidth = c.measureText(str).width;
                  if (wordWidth > maxWidth) {
                      maxWidth = wordWidth;

                  }
              };

          for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
              words = sections[i].split(' ');
              index = 1;

              while (words.length > 0 && index <= words.length) {

                  str = words.slice(0, index).join(' ');
                  wordWidth = c.measureText(str).width;

                  if (wordWidth > fitWidth) {
                      if (index === 1) {
                          // Falls to this case if the first word in words[] is bigger than fitWidth
                          // so we print this word on its own line; index = 2 because slice is
                          str = words.slice(0, 1).join(' ');
                          words = words.splice(1);
                      } else {
                          str = words.slice(0, index - 1).join(' ');
                          words = words.splice(index - 1);
                      }

                      printNextLine(str);

                      index = 1;
                  } else {
                      index++;
                  }
              }

              // The left over words on the last line
              if (index > 0) {
                  printNextLine(words.join(' '));
              }


          }

          maxHeight = lineHeight * (currentLine);

          if (DEBUG) {
              if(maxWidth < this.text_width){
              maxWidth =this.text_width;
              }  
              c.strokeRect(x, y, maxWidth, maxHeight); 
          }

          if (!draw) {
              return {
                  height: maxHeight,
                  width: maxWidth
              };
          }
```

but if my string have two lines, and the first line begin with bold, the second line don't apeear in the canvas..

Comment: Cmon now, you can put more effort into asking this question than this. No one is going to read through that much code. Give us the MINIMUM code required to understand what the issue is.

Comment: What are you replacing `</strong>` with?

Comment: @Shmiddty with #b#.. so the text that i want to be in bold are between #b#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i rewrite the method PrintNextLine, and it works fine.

```
 var printNextLine = function (str) {
          if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
              // see below for better implementation!
              String.prototype.startsWith = function (str){
                return this.indexOf(str) == 0;
              };
            }
          if (draw) {
              var comp=0;
              var comp2=0;
              var comp_2=0;
              var comp2_2=0;
              if (str.startsWith("#b#")){
                  bold=str.split("#b#");
                  for(var i=0;i<bold.length;i++){
                      if(i%2!=0){
                          for(var a=0;a<i;a++){
                              comp+=c.measureText(bold[a]).width
                          }
                          c.font = "Bold "+font_size + ' ' + font_family;
                          c.fillText(bold[i], x+comp, y + (lineHeight * currentLine));
                          comp=0;
                      }else{
                          for(var b=0;b<i;b++){
                              comp2+=c.measureText(bold[b]).width
                          }
                          c.font = font_size + ' ' + font_family;
                          c.fillText(bold[i], x+comp2, y + (lineHeight * currentLine));
                          comp2=0;
                      }
                  }  

              }else{
                  if (str.indexOf("#b#") != -1){
                      bold_2=str.split("#b#");
                      for(var i=0;i<bold_2.length;i++){
                          if(i%2==0){
                              for(var a=0;a<i;a++){
                                  comp_2+=c.measureText(bold_2[a]).width
                              }
                              c.font = font_size + ' ' + font_family;
                              c.fillText(bold_2[i], x+comp_2, y + (lineHeight * currentLine));
                              comp_2=0;
                          }else{
                              for(var b=0;b<i;b++){
                                  comp2_2+=c.measureText(bold_2[b]).width
                              }
                              c.font = "Bold "+font_size + ' ' + font_family;
                              c.fillText(bold_2[i], x+comp2_2, y + (lineHeight * currentLine));
                              comp2_2=0;
                          }
                      }
                  }else{
                      c.font = font_size + ' ' + font_family;
                      c.fillText(str, x, y + (lineHeight * currentLine));
                  }

              }


          }

            currentLine++;
            wordWidth = c.measureText(str).width;
            if (wordWidth > maxWidth) {
                maxWidth = wordWidth;

                  }
                    };
```